# Why is R's purrr::map() trying to convert my output to a function?

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I'm sure there is a simple explanation for this, but the brain fog is strong this morning and I'm at a loss. I am trying to use purrr::map() to call a function that sometimes returns an NA, but I keep getting an error message:

"Error: Can't convert a logical vector to function"

Here's a simplified case that returns the error:

```
library(tidyverse)

test <- function(x){
  return(NA)
}

a <- map(.x = 1:2,.f = test())
```

R classifies NA as a logical variable, but I don't understand why map() is trying to convert this variable to a function when I return it. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think you want `.f = test`?

Comment: `test()` is a call because you included the parameter delimiters. If you just used its name, `test` you might have succeeded. (Once the call got evaluated it returned a logical vector.) The answer to your anthropomorphic  question in the title is "because it needed or wanted a function".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
a <- map(.x = 1:2,.f = test)
```

without the parenthesis. The `.f` argument needs to be a function -- you do not want to call your function there.

Note that `class(test)` is "function" but `class(test())` is not -- it's "logical" in this case. Leave the parenthesis off when referring to the function itself. Otherwise what you've typed is the same as

```
# these are the same
a <- map(.x = 1:2, .f = test())
a <- map(.x = 1:2, .f = NA)
```

Comment: Oh boy. I knew it would be something simple. Thank you so much!